# Will a virus/malware travel between devices when logged into the same Google account

Tags: malware, google

If my laptop/desktop got infected with malware or some kind of a virus, will it be safe to log in the account on my laptop to my new PC or will it spread to it because I used the same account for new PC as I do now for my laptop?

Will anything happen? Is it safe or if I get infected, I shouldn`t use those accounts anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Google Drive set up to sync files, then the infected files might transfer over. But to get infected, those files would need to be run on the new machine.

Just having infected files does not mean that you are infected.

Comment: In general I agree, but there are very few occasions where viewing may already initiate the infection, e.g. if there is a vulnerability in the file manager ( e.g. Windows explorer Imageviewer). Or in case a virus scanner can be infected by a specially manipulated archive file. We had such vulnerabilities in the last years so this is not a pure theory.